# Why does a blowup of $\mathbb{A}^2$ about the origin result in the Möbius band?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

I am new to learning about blowups, so I was searching for an easy example to wrap my mind around the concept. I came across this document https://homepage.univie.ac.at/herwig.hauser/Publications/ggt05-hauser.pdf and on the top of page 5, it gives a brief example of a blowup of $\mathbb{A}^2$. It says, “for $Z=0$ the origin in the real plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, we obtain (cum grano salis) for $\tilde{\mathbb{A}^2}$ the Möbius band in $\mathbb{R}^3$.” Here, the blowup is being done with $Z=0$ as its center.

I‘m not seeing why this is what the blowup should be, but it’s entirely possible that can be attributed to my lack of current understanding on the topic. If someone could explain it, it would be much appreciated! I would also love to hear other “simple/beginner” examples of blowups.

Comment: The subset $\{(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, \theta) \mid r\geq 0, \theta \in [0, \pi) \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2\times \bigl([0, \pi]/ (0=\pi) \bigr)$ projecting down to the first two coordinates exhibits this subset as a blowup of $\mathbb{R}^2$ at the origin. This is the `double spiral staircase' formed by a line rotating around the origin from $0$ to $\pi$, and the top and the bottom identified, thus the M\"obius band.

Comment: @NarukiMasuda This should be an answer, not a comment. Would you care to record it below?

Comment: Ok, true, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subset $\{(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta, \theta) \mid r\geq 0, \theta \in [0, \pi) \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2\times \bigl([0, \pi]/ (0=\pi) \bigr)$ projecting down to the first two coordinates exhibits this subset as a blowup of $\mathbb{R}^2$ at the origin. This is the `double spiral staircase' formed by a line rotating around the origin from $0$ to $\pi$, and the top and the bottom identified, thus the Mobius band.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your first sentence? I believe that I understand your second statement, but I'm a bit unsure where this subset came from. Is it part of the definition of the blowup of a point? Why does projecting onto the first two coordinates exhibit the blow up?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}P^1$ consists of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ through 0, which is parametrized by the angle $[0, \pi]$ with 0 and $\pi$ identified. Through this identification, my projection is precisely the projection $\pi$ in your reference. I was a bit sloppy about that taking the Zariski closure adds the copy of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ above the origin (because the identification $\theta\leftrightarrow (a:b)$ is transcendental), but you can unpack this to get an algebraic equation, or you can see that already in the usual (finer) topology all possible points need to be added into the exceptional divisor.

Comment: To be clear, the subset I wrote is algebraically $\{(x, y, (a: b)\mid bx=ay \} \subset \mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}P^1$.

Comment: Ah, thank you! The explanation about the subset did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, you are replacing the point at which you blow up with "the straight lines passing through that point" with the direction in which you follow the line not part of the data. Since you are on $\mathbb{A}^2$ this corresponds kind of to enlarge the point to a circle and then quotienting the circle over the antipodal map. Thus, with one go around the circle you would wrap twice around your blowup, which you can see as the fact that you need to "go around the boundary of the Moebius strip twice to come back to the starting point".

Notice however that the blow up is not compact. Hopefully, someone with a deeper understanding in algebraic geometry than me can explain better the technicalities involved.

Comment: Thank you an intuitive idea of what's happening! When I enlarge my point, why do I end up with a circle rather than a disc? Is this something that is just understood/accepted? Of course, doing this would result in $\mathbb{R}P^2$ as my quotient, which I know is not correct from the punchline of the example.